# php,mysql,html - Display SQL query(conjunction) properly in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I want to display the name of the doctor that will only recur once and his specialization for the proper limit of it. I have here my query

```
select a.emp_fname,a.emp_lname,b.hcp_name, c.*, d.*,e.spec_type
from ehr_employee a
inner join ehr_c_hcp_emp c
on a.emp_id=c.emp_id
inner join ehr_hcp b
on b.hcp_id=c.hcp_id
inner join ehr_c_doc_spec d
on d.emp_id=a.emp_id
inner join ehr_specialization e
on e.spec_id=d.spec_id
```

Whereas the `ehr_c_hcp_emp` has
`hcp_emp_id` `emp_id` `hcp_id` (Conjunction for the employee and hcp table). 
And the `ehr_c_doc_spec` has `doc_spec_id` `emp_id` `spec_id` (Conjunction for the employee and specialization table). Why is that because the doctor/employee can be in 1 or more different hospitals and can have 1 or more specialization. 
The query above display this result

```
emp_fname   emp_lname   hcp_name   spec_type
John        Doe         Hospital   Cardio
John        Doe         Clinic     Cardio
John        Doe         Hospital   Psych
John        Doe         Clinic     Psych
```

I have my php-html code written in while like this

```
 <?php
$sel_admin = "*The query above*";
$rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
{      
  echo" <tr class='gradeX'> ";
  echo "<td>" .$row['emp_fname']." ".$row['emp_lname']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['hcp_name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['spec_type']. "</td>";
  echo"</tr>";
}
  ?>
```

And it just produce just like the query above

What I want to achieve is something like this in a single row

```
John Doe    Hospital    Psych
            Clinic      Cardio
```

NOTE: I also have many data like that i just displayed it like that visualization

Comment: so add some code to only output a name if it's different from the previous row. `$prev = null; while(...) { If ($prev != $cur_name) { output name; $prev = $cur_name }}`

Comment: I think that will display them on two separate rows??

Comment: then you'd need even more code to count how many dupes there are and issue appropriate rowspan headers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the `output name;` you've said?

Answer (score 0):

My personal solution would be create simple result set builder, something like this. Then you could do another foreach in row. Question is, do you want or not new row for each record. Because then @marc-b answer is correct and works for multipage.

```
$tableData = [];
$sqlData = [
    0 => [
        'userId' => 3,
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'group' => 'Good'
    ],
    1 => [
        'userId' => 3,
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'group' => 'Bad'
    ]
];

foreach ($sqlData as $item) {
    if (!isset($tableData[$item['userId']])) {
        $tableData[$item['userId']] = [
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'groups' => []
        ];
    }

    $tableData[$item['userId']]['groups'][] = $item['group'];
}

$tableData = [
    3 => [
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'groups' => [
            0 => 'Good',
            1 => 'Bad'
        ]
    ]
];
```